# Pass in addition fields to model creation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Well hello there,

When cleaning up my controller class I was wondering where to put extra fields when creating a model. In the `StoreAdvertisementRequest` class there are some validation rules applied.
Next I also want to make sure the new advertisement is coupled to a `user_id` and a certain `status_id` field.

But how does that work in combination with a `make:request` request and the method `$request->validated()`.

Is there a way to sneak these in?

```
public function store(StoreAdvertisementRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    // pass these in...
    $validated['user_id'] = Auth::id();
    $validated['status_id'] = AdvertisementStatus::WAITING_FOR_PROPOSAL;

    $advertisement = Advertisement::create($request->validated());
```

Answer (score 1):

just merge the arrays

```
$additionalFields = [
    'user_id' => Auth::id(), 
    'status_id' => AdvertisementStatus::WAITING_FOR_PROPOSAL,
];

$advertisement = Advertisement::create(array_merge($request->validated(), $additionalFields));
```

Answer (score 1):

You first validate the request using the `$request->validated()` method, then add extra fields to the validated request data:

```
public function store(StoreAdvertisementRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    // Add extra fields
    $validated['user_id'] = Auth::id();
    $validated['status_id'] = AdvertisementStatus::WAITING_FOR_PROPOSAL;

    $advertisement = Advertisement::create($validated);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this function to your 'StoreAdvertisementRequest' class,
it will automatically appended to `$request->validated()`.

```
/**
 * Prepare the data for validation.
 */
protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        'user_id'   => Auth::id(),
        'status_id' => AdvertisementStatus::WAITING_FOR_PROPOSAL
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
public function store(StoreAdvertisementRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    // pass these in...
    $validated['user_id'] = Auth::id();
    $validated['status_id'] = AdvertisementStatus::WAITING_FOR_PROPOSAL;

    $advertisement = Advertisement::create($request->validated() + $validated);
```